# Can Lombok or an Aspect add a logger to a lambda using an annotation

Tags: java, logging, lambda, lombok, aspect

I would like to use either an annotation (Lombok) or an aspect to include a logger for all my Java 8 Lambda's and I would like the flexibility of being able to change the logger (Slf4J or other) if I decide I want to do so.

I specifically do not want to inherit it...I do not want to have to define my own Functional interface wrappers in order to do so.
So please do not provide an answer with this tack.

So, in short, if I have Lambda's that depend solely on the java.util.function.* interfaces, how would I be able to provide a specific logger per lambda that is woven in, with a Lombok annotation or an aspect?

Comment: Side point: slf4j isn't a logger, it's a logging facade (abstraction). You still have to choose/configure a logger to do the actual logging. This means you can wire in slf4j everywhere and still have the flexibility to change the actual logger at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the correction...